# How to troubleshoot "java.lang.NumberFormatException: null"

Tags: java, numberformatexception

Following is a part of the code I have written in java. I am getting an error in the line 
"c= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());"
please help

```
public class decipher
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int [][] plainText= new int [16][16];
        int [][] key= new int [16][16];
        int [][] num= new int [16][16];
        int [][] finalKey= new int [16][16];
        int [][] cipherText= new int [16][16];
        int c=0,a=0,i,j,m,n;
        System.out.println("Enter cipher text character by character:");
        for (i=0;i<16;i++)
        {
            for (j=0;j<16;j++)
            {
                c= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                if (c<257)
```

I am getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542) at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) at
>   decipher.main(decipher.java:23)

Comment: The buffered reader will return `null` when there are no more lines in the file it reads. You should always check for that.

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: `if ((input = reader.readLine()) == null)`, or `input = reader.readLine(); if (input == null)`

Answer (score 2):

According to 
[Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()), readLine() returns:

> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached **without reading any characters**

So, your statement is then equivalent to `Integer.parseInt(null)`. This is why there is a **java.lang.NumberFormatException**.

Your error can be fixed by using [read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read())
instead of readLine(), as you are taking char inputs.